# Clamp Amp meter trip GFCI outlet?

Tags: electrical

I was testing how much amp my heater was taking up by testing the Amp but it tripped the outlet. I tried the test 2 times more and tripped every time. Why does the clamp amp meter trip the outlet?

Comment: Since you aren't using a clamp meter (pretty hard to trip the breaker with that), I assume you're using a normal two probe multimeter. Where are you putting the probes? What settings are you using on the meter?

Comment: Hmm. I thought "can't be clamp" because how in the world could that trip anything. But says "Clamp" in the title. **Make/model # of meter?** **Make/model # of heater?** **Picture of how you are using the meter?**

Comment: I'm using a Commercial electric ms 2002 clamp meter.  If this is weird, there must be a short somewhere.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but: This is a clamp meter that also has leads for other things. How are you using it to measure amps?

Comment: Thinking you are moving the wires to use the meter.  Possible the wire insulation is damaged/ nicked somewhere, and your moving it to use the meter is causing a short.

Comment: In clamp AMP mode be sure not to attach either of the wire leads to anything, instead, unplug them.

Comment: yeah, maybe while the clamp was around the hot wire, it touched the other wire causing a short.

Comment: I suspect it has more to do with *how* you separated the hot wire from the neutral so you could get the clamp around it. Are you using a commercially made line splitter designed for that purpose? Or did you modify the cord in some way?